# 'Cannot create a DbQuery for '...' because it is not a query type. Use the DbContext.Set method to create a DbSet instead.'

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have an entity that I create with

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        // ... other setup
    }
```

When I try query with

```
dbContext.Query<MyEntity>()
```

I get the exception

> Cannot create a DbQuery for 'MyEntity' because it is not a query type.
>   Use the DbContext.Set method to create a DbSet instead

From my understanding, in EF Core an "entity" is something different than "that which you can query."

I tried adding in

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Query<MyEntity>();
```

but then I get the error

> The entity type 'MyEntity' cannot be added to the model because a
>   query type with the same name already exists.

when I create a new migration.

So do I have to create a wrapper over `MyEntity` and add it is a query? Will I have to go through this exercise for every entity? Is the idea that I design a different read model? Help me out here.

Comment: The error message is telling you what to do - use `Set` method instead of `Query`, e.g. `dbContext.Set<MyEntity>()`. Although the returned `DbSet<T>` can be used for other operations, it implements `IQueryable<T>`, i.e. is the base for reading (and querying) the entity (database table).